# SQL query within SSIS Script Component

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am writing a Visual Basis 2012 SSIS script in which I want to ask the database for several values (ordinary select statement).

I have no idea how I am supposed to do that. I found quite a few examples of such scripts, however none worked for me (perhaps because most of them were written for older versions of VB). I have added connection manager (Native OLE DB/SQL Server Native Client 11.0) called Conn1 to the Script Component Connection Managers. I have no idea how to refer to it in VB script. Step by step solution or actually working example would be great as I'm quite new to the topic.

Comment: Why can't you just dynamically build dynamic SELECT statement in script task and then execute that dynamic query in Execute SQL Task or Data Flow

Comment: I could, however I will need to do such things several times in this process therefore I think it would be more elegant if I could just do it within one script component.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the script you tried, and the exact error message you got so we can help debug it.

Comment: If you want to do SQL access in a script object, you use the same code as if you were in a VB application.  This should get you started:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308656